# is my add method in binary search tree correct

Tags: java

I want to implement code for inserting a new Node in a binary search tree in java  so please check if my code is correct ,,, Here is my method :

```
public class BinarySearchTree {
      …

      public boolean add(int value) {
            if (root == null) {
                  root = new BSTNode(value);
                  return true;
            } else
                  return root.add(value);
      }
}
        public class BSTNode {
         …

      public boolean add(int value) {
            if (value == root.data)
                  return false;
            else if (value <root.data) {
                  if (root.left == null) {
                        root.left = new BSTNode(value);
                        return true;
                  } else
                        return root.left.add(value);
            } else if (value > root.data) {
                  if (root.right == null) {
                        root.right = new BSTNode(value);
                        return true;
                  } else
                        return root.right.add(value);
            }
            return false;
      }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review. Please post your whole classes, there is no need to remove code from them. See [Checklist for how to write a good Code Review question](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/6429/42632)

Comment: Checking that a piece of code works is not really what we do here. That's your job. We require the code in question to be fully working, and expect that you have tested it. Then, we suggest improvements and warn against based practices

Comment: Please include the complete implementation of `BinarySearchTree` and `BSTNode` (no `...`) The references to `root` in `BSTNode.add` method suggest that this class doesn't work as intended, the implementation looks broken. I'm putting this on hold until you post the complete code. Please test it well.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to be correct.

However this code can result in unbalanced trees (like if you add all numbers in increasing order).

To keep it balanced you can use the techniques described for [self-balancing trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-balancing_binary_search_tree)

Comment: Besides giving a link to Wikipedia, consider perhaps applying some of those techniques as examples given the OP's code.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks okay but what excites me is more about design. Rather than conforming to the concrete BST for add/delete/search, you could create a interface and develop concrete implementations of tree like binary search tree, balanced binary tree,etc.

```
public interface Tree {

    public void addNode(Object arg0);
    public void deleteNode(Object arg0);
    public void searchNode(Object arg0);

}
```

and you create your own flavor of the BST by implementing the tree interface like this :

```
public class BinarySearchTree implements Tree {

private Node root;

public BinarySearchTree()
{
    this.root = null;
}

public BinarySearchTree(Object data)
{
    this.root = new Node(data);
}


@Override
public void addNode(Object data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stu


}

@Override
public void deleteNode(Object arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void searchNode(Object arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

}
```

and finally have the Node data object ready for cooking with a simple implementation like this:

public class Node {

```
private Node left;
private Node right;
private Object data;


public Node(Object data)
{
    this.data = data;
    this.left = null;
    this.right = null;
}

public boolean hasLeftChild()
{
    return left == null;
}

public boolean hasRightChild()
{
    return right == null;
}

public void setData(Object data)
{
    this.data = data;
}

public Object getData()
{
    return this.data;
}


public Node getRightChild()
   {
         return this.right;        

   } 

   public Node getLeftChild()
   {
         return this.left;        

   } 

}
```